# LinearLayout change android:layoutAnimation programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-linearlayout

Is there any way to change `android:layoutAnimation` to a different animation resource programmatically using Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to change `android:layoutAnimation` to a different animation resource programmatically using Java?

**Yes** : you can use [**`LayoutAnimationController`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html)

- A layout animation controller is used to animated a `layout's`, or a `view` group's, children. Each child uses the same animation but for every one of them, the animation starts at a different time. A `layout animation controller` is used by `ViewGroup` to compute the delay by which each child's animation start must be offset

**HERE IS WORKING EXAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView=findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        LayoutAnimationController anim = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_down);
        rootView.setLayoutAnimation(anim);
    }


}
```

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**R.anim.scale_down**

```
 <layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/scale_up" />
```

**@anim/scale_up**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot.  Didn't know about AnimationUtils.